# grep strings which contains 4 or 6 characters count only in bash

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to print only the words which contains 4 or 6 characters count only in a line in bash. I tried couple of things which didn't work. Can someone let me know how can we make this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: @MichałSzkudlarek I tried `grep -o -w '\w\{4,6\}'` which filters both 4,5,6 characters count words but i dont want 5 characters word..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To capture words that are either four or six characters long:

```
$ echo four fives sixsix | grep -Eow '\w{4}|\w{6}'
four
sixsix
```

`-w` tells grep to match only complete words

`-o` tells grep to print only the matches and not their context.

`-E` tells grep to use extended regular expressions so that we don't have to type so many backslashes

`\w{4}` matches words that are four characters long while `\w{6}` matches words that are six characters long.  `|` is logical-or.

Answer (score 1):

in case yoiu dont have GNU version (especialy option `-o` on grep)

Sed version (posix compliant)

```
sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ /g;s/.*/ & /' -e ':cycle' -e 's/ [^ ]\{1,3\} / /g;s/ [^ ]\{7,\} / /g;s/ [^ ]\{5\} / /g;t cycle' -e 's/^ *//;s/ *$//;/^ *$/d' YourFile
```

awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i++<=NR;)if(l=length($i)==4||l==6)print $i}' YourFile
```